# Ordering system - id number per order (not row) in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, unique

ok i have 98% of the code done but struggling on the last bit. I'm creating a ordering system and i'm taking values from one page, sending them to a php page and inserting them into a mysql db like this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Cannot connect to mysql server");
           mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Cannot select database");

            if (isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row => $data) {
                    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (id,project_ref,supp_short_code,om_part_no,description,quantity,cost_of_items,cost_total) VALUES('', '".$data['project_ref']."', '".$data['supp_short_code']."', '".$data['om_part_no']."', '".$data['description']."', '".$data['quantity_input']."', '".$data['cost_of_items']."', '".$data['cost_total_td']."') ") or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
```

Which is great (and i know i'm not protecting against sql injection, etc) but there could be multiple rows being inserted into the db using the above code, but what i need is for the user to later be able to pull back an order based on one id number. So how do i insert an id number into this insert query so it matches all rows and is definitely unique in the db and ideally auto-incrementing (i'm aware this is going to be tricky considering theres multiple rows!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do in a case like this is have two tables, `orders` and `order_detail`

The `orders` table would have your `grand totals`, `order date`, `customer id`, etc.

The `order_detail` table would have an entry for each individual item.. `part_no`, `quantity`, `cost`, `extended_cost` but would link back to the `orders` table by an `order_id`.

You'd end up selecting like:

`SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_detail ON orders.order_id = order_detail.order_id WHERE orders.order_id = '1'`

Answer (score 2):

Add a column to your `orders` table called `BatchID`. Then, generate a GUID in PHP, and modify your `INSERT` statement accordingly.

[See here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) for details on generating a GUID.

```
function GUID()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
    {
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
    }

    return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your 'id' field is meant to hold the autoincrementing id for each order, you will want to add a new insert prior to your current insert statement that will just add a record to a table with an auto-incrementing primary key. Then take this new primary key and associate it with your current table instead of the current 'id' or in addition to the current 'id' field.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Cannot connect to mysql server");
       mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Cannot select database");

        if (isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data'])) {
            result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders_to_order SET order_primary = NULL");
            $orderId = mysql_insert_id();
            foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row => $data) {
                $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (id,project_ref,supp_short_code,om_part_no,description,quantity,cost_of_items,cost_total) VALUES(".$orderId.", '".$data['project_ref']."', '".$data['supp_short_code']."', '".$data['om_part_no']."', '".$data['description']."', '".$data['quantity_input']."', '".$data['cost_of_items']."', '".$data['cost_total_td']."') ") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
```